# A function to check if the word has an increasing or decreasing sequence of chars in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm new in C.
I've been asked to write a function that checks if the string has increasing/decreasing sequence of letters based on ASCII values + not includes white spaces(tabs,new lines etc.).
For example: **demo** is a very increasing string
             **beef** is an increasing string
             **aa** or **zzz** is an increasing string
             **tonic** is a very decreasing string
             **spoon** is a decreasing string
             **suddenly** has no clear sequence. 
So I wrote this code,it works but not so well..can you help me to improve it a little bit?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f_sequence (char str[]);

int main()
{

   char strl[101]; 
   printf("your string is:\n");
   scanf("%s\n", strl);
   f_sequence(strl);

 return 0;

}

void f_sequence(char str[])

{
      int increase=0;
      int decrease=0;
      int match=0;
      int i = 1;
       if(!str[0])
        printf("empty");
       else if(!str[1])
        printf("need more chars");
       for(i=1; str[i]; i++)
       {
          if (str[i] == str[i-1])
          match = 1;
          if (str[i] > str[i-1])
          increase = 1;
          if (str[i] < str[i-1])
          decrease = 1;
       } 
        if((decrease==1) && (increase==0) && (match==0))
         printf("we have a very descreasing sequence in here");
        if((decrease==0) && (increase==1) && (match==0))
         printf("we have a very increasing sequence in here");   
        if((decrease==1) && (increase==0) && (match==1))
         printf("we have a descreasing sequence in here");
        if((decrease==0) && (increase==1) && (match==1))
         printf("we have an increasing sequence in here");
        if((decrease==0) && (increase==0) && (match==1))
         printf("we have an increasing sequence in here");
        if((decrease==1) && (increase==1))
         printf("not increasing and not decreasing");
        puts("");   
}
```

Comment: What about a string with 1 char (`"y"`)? The empty string?

Comment: "it works but not so well" be more specific please.

Comment: unrelated: don't end the scanf conversion string with white space (no `scanf("...\n", ...)`).

Comment: "*aa or zzz is an increasing string*" - That you shouldn´t be the case. You should add another option to check if the subsequent characters are equal and print a relative message accordingly.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have a problem with the white spaces..don't know where I should put the condition

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio ohh its not my case its a part of the exercise definition

Comment: @pmg you're right! is that correct to write it like this  if(!str[0])
        printf("empty"); ??

Comment: @pmg Ok, change it, thanks

Comment: Your for loop works, but is not the idiomatic way to cycle through characters of a string `for(i=1; str[i]; i++)` .  It would be better to use `for(i=1; i<strlen(str); i++)`

Comment: Note that your code goes on to analyze the data after an empty string or a string with just one character, which is probably not sensible.  IMO, you should end the `printf()` strings with newlines and remove the `puts("");` call.  Or use `puts()` to instead of `printf()` without the need to add newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore whitespaces, you can use `isspace` from `<ctype.h>` and skip in your calculations:

```
   for(i = 1; str[i]; i++)
   {   
        if (isspace((unsigned char)str[i])) continue;
        ...
   }
```

But as is, you can't read input string with whitespaces as `scanf` with `%s` would stop reading at the first whitespace. You need [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) to read a line (so that you could read a string with whitespaces):

```
int main()
{
    char strl[101];
    printf("your string is:\n");
    if (fgets(strl, sizeof strl, stdin)) {
        char *p = strchr(strl, '\n');
        if (p) *p = '\0'; // Remove newline if present
        f_sequence(strl);
    }   
}
```

`fgets` would also read the newline character if there's space in the buffer which you may want to remove as shown (include `<string.h>` for `strchr`).

Comment: Note that using `strl[strcspn(strl, "\n")] = '\0';` zaps the newline without visible conditionals or local variables.  It handles a missing newline quite happily.  You can also replace `"\n"` with `"\r\n"` to handle Unix (`\n`), Windows (`\r`, `\n`) or old Mac (`\r` only) line endings.

Comment: You helped me a lot.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like below to remove whitespaces:

```
void removeSpaces(char *str) 
{ 
    // To keep track of non-space character count 
    int count = 0; 

    // Traverse the given string. If current character 
    // is not space, then place it at index 'count++' 
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) 
        if (str[i] != ' ') 
            str[count++] = str[i]; // here count is 
                                   // incremented 
    str[count] = '\0'; 
}
```

And then add this function in the first line of `f_sequence` function. like this:

```
removeSpaces(str);
```

Comment: @Krisi3 You're welcome mate. did it work?

Comment: Yes it is! thanks again

Comment: @Krisi3 Glad it helped. You can "accept" one the answers so others who come here later can find their answer quicker.